# Sun, Sunset, Sunrise, Orbits and Allah's Throne

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sahih-bukhari

I have a question about Hadith 3199, Book 59, Hadith 10. In there is told by Abu Dar that he heard from Muhammad(pbuh) that the sun at sunset travels to the Throne of Allah and has to get permission before it is allowed to rise up again. It ends with telling that that is is what verse 36:38 of the Quran is refering to. Is this a correct Hadith?

The chain must be correct to make it inside Sahih Bukhari and the narrator must be a trustworthy person. But is it possible that he heard it wrong from Muhammad(pbuh), misunderstanded it or even confused it with other things?

In the past it would not be as strange as it is now in this scientific age. We know now that the earth rotates around the sun and around itself. It is not the sun that goes around the earth. The day that the sun comes up from the west will be caused by the earth that starts to rotate in the opposite way. And the sun too is moving inside the Milky Way galaxy and I though that the verse in the Hadith refers to that last movement instead of refering to the sunset and the sunrise. We also know that the sun at sunset is still shining at the opposite part of the earth. If we think at night that the sun went to the Throne of Allah what should the people at the other side of the earth think while for them it is day on that same moment?

Is it just me who does not understand how that is possible, or is science not that far yet, or is it symbolic? Can it be misunderstood and narrated by a good man through a correct chain?

Comment: Science cannot explain everything to reason with our logic. Above science comes faith. So we believe without seeing and without asking questions in matters that exceed our wisdom. In the Quran it's said that everything prostrates to Allah ﷻ, that's more than enough for us believers.

Comment: Isn't this topic already covered in [Isn't this hadith about sunset unscientific?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/isnt-this-hadith-about-sunset-unscientific).

Answer (score 2):

A hadith is Sahih means that its chain is connected and that all the links in it are trustworthy and competent people. But they are still human so it is possible that one of the narrators made a mistake in hearing or conveying the hadith. But the likelihood of that happening is very low.

Further the Sun's prostration is affirmed in the Quran. It is written:

> See you not that whoever is in the heavens and whoever is on the earth, and the sun, and the moon, and the stars, and the mountains, and the trees, and Ad-Dawâbb [moving (living) creatures, beasts], and many of mankind prostrate themselves to Allah.
>
> https://islamawakened.com/quran/22/18/

The manner and nature of this prostration is not known. It is possible that its prostration is not observable by our senses or that it has a different form, just like the prostration of the mountains, trees and animals etc.